# Android Key Hash Can't be generated

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I am trying to create a Facebook integrated android app.
I tried to generate the Key Hash using the following command:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\test\debug.keystore" > c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt

It got successfully executed in the Command Prompt by giving the password :'android'

When I opened the file 'debug.txt' I got the following:
[image]

How can I solve this and get the real Key Hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot openssl and such

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | 
openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Make sure to install openssl and have it in your PATH